# UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) with SteamSpy not working

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, response, urlfetch

If you got to steam spy link : https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=tag&tag=Early+Access
You get what you expect.

However using the same URL in

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=tag&tag=Early+Access");
```

Only returns the api `home page` which looks like this:

https://steamspy.com/api.php

Why is `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` ignoring the request part of the URL?

Comment: When I tested `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=tag&tag=Early+Access");`, a JSON data is returned. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. So, as a direction, for example, when you do the url encode like `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=tag&tag=Early%2BAccess");`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi there, when I type in the url encode as listed, in the Logger.log, I still get a block of text that is the api homepage. The Code looks like this;  'var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=tag&tag=Early%2BAccess");'
  Logger.log(response);

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, both can be used. So in your situation, for example, when you request the URL using the curl command, what result will you obtain?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with the api since august. Returns only api description - no data